# Populating a JTable from a .txt file

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I know similar questions have been asked before, and I've been browsing through pretty much all of them, but I still can't populate my JTable by loading data from a file (from a .txt file).

The way I save the file is each column's info separated by a "|". So you get this:

LastName|FirstName|ID|LandPhone|MobilePhone|

For example, you get this:
Doe|John|1248234834|021324234234|0732553535|
Doe|Jane|1492349324|021432434325|0735345345|

And so on. The code I'm using to open the .txt file is this:

```
private void deschideMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    String line = null;
    DefaultTableModel dtm =  (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

    FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Fisiere text","txt");
    jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    jfc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    jfc.setDialogTitle("Deschideti un tabel...");
    jfc.setFileFilter(filter);        
    if(jfc.showOpenDialog(this)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File file = jfc.getSelectedFile();

        try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Vector data= new Vector();
            StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(line,"|");

            while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String nextToken = st1.nextToken();
                data.add(nextToken);

            }
            System.out.println(data);
            dtm.addRow(data);
        }

        br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } 

}
```

Problem is, I'm always getting this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.justifyRows(DefaultTableModel.java:265)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.insertRow(DefaultTableModel.java:375)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.addRow(DefaultTableModel.java:350)
```

If I use the print method to see what I'm getting, I'm always getting the first line right, and then it crashes. It never reaches the second line. How do you force it to go to the second line? And what's up with the 0>=0 exception? From what I understood from the other topics related to populating a JTable from a .txt file, it has to do with the model not knowing about the number of columns?

This is seriously confusing. I've always wondered why does it have to be so complicated in programming, everything and anything, but that's just a rhetorical question.

Comment: if the model doesn't know about the amount of columns, simply create it after reading the first line. 
`Object[] title= line.split("|");
model = new DefaultTableModel(title, 0);
table = new JTable(model);`

Comment: Well I already have a table in my JFrame, it's called "table".

If you look at my code, I have this declaration:

`DefaultTableModel dtm =  (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();`

So shouldn't my dtm already know the number of columns since it is using "table.getModel()"? (it's using my already existing table's model)

Comment: in this case your tablemodel needs 5 columns.

Comment: But shouldn't the model already know that? Why do I need to tell it again that it needs 5 columns if I already use the `table.getModel()` declaration? Shouldn't the table take all the necessary information from that?

Comment: thats what i mean. maybe your existing table has less than 5 columns?

Comment: Wait... rows or columns? :))

My table has 5 columns. The file that I'm saving (so that I can load back from it) has 5 columns as well (5 fields) and then it moves to the next line.

It's LastName|FirstName|ID|LandPhone|MobilePhone| - then it's the same on the next line. The problem is, it never reaches the next line and it never inserts the line in the actual table.

Comment: if i look at this line: `Doe|John|1248234834|021324234234|0732553535| Doe|Jane|1492349324|021432434325|0735345345|` it does look to me , as if its just 1 line and not 2. also the way you do it, you would get a 6th result which is empty (given these are 2 lines).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130414/discussion-between-robert-ruxandrescu-and-xtremebaumer).

Comment: `So shouldn't my dtm already know the number of columns since it is using "table.getModel()"?`  - it only knows that if you created the DefaultTableModel with 5 columns. The table is not a mind reader, it doesn't know what data you plan to load in the table.

Comment: True, and therefore it should be able to add each row as I populate it, with the dtm.addRow() method. But it doesn't.

It's like first you need to tell him "add a row" and then "populate that row with this information". But shouldn't that be automatically done, both of these 2 steps, with the addRow() method?

I don't understand what the issue is. I'm creating a Vector, I populate that Vector with the data from the first line in the file, and then I want to add that Vector on the first line. And so on, until I reach the end of the file. It shouldn't be this complicated.